# Estimate the Numbers of samples required for each variable

Tags: confidence-interval, sampling, sample

I am tasked to help with organizing the driving experiments for a robot.

The goal is that for each Terrain Class like forest, wet-meadows, dry-meadows we will measure the time it takes the robot to move through it. As I understand, we have two important factors: 1) slope of the terrain and 2) the feature-class represented as `cid` in the graphic below.

We have 5 slope intervals ranging from 0-5° up to 25-30°. As you can see in the graphic below, most of the area is between 15 and 25°.

I now want to estimate, how many areas [m²] per class we need to drive through to get an adequate sample size for each feature and for each slope.

I don't know how to start with it, my naive approach would be to cover at least 20% of each feature for each slope when planning the route.

The advanced option would be to choose the sample size according to a 95% confidence interval. How would the different slope categories play into that?

What would you recommend as a strategy to make sure every class and slope is covered. Is there further literature that can help me understand the problem better?

---

X-Axis: Slope in degrees.

Y-Axis: The percentage of coverage each feature for each slope has on the total area of the test side.

Legend: Class-Identifier e.g., 11 = Forest, 81 = Shrubland, 431 = Paths, etc.

[image: X-Achsis: Slope, Y-Achsis: The percentage of coverage each feature for each slope has on the total area of the test side]

Comment: Start by formulating a clear, quantitative objective: tell us what an "adequate" sample size must achieve.

Comment: An “adequate” sample size should represent each feature and slope so, that we have can measure the average time it takes to traverse a feature. This data will then be used by a routing algorithm to calculate the fastest route from any location A in the test side to  a location B.  Sorry I am not good at stating clear mathematical descriptions.

Comment: According to your characterization, an "adequate" sample will make one observation of each feature-slope combination.  You will likely find that *inadequate* because you will discover it yields *highly uncertain* estimates of average traversal time.  One way to approach this would be to stipulate what confidence you want to have that the mean times are within specified limits of precision.